# How to debug Flask BuildError

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to debug a BuildError in a flask 0.8 app. The error occurs in the function `personal_open_account()` while trying to render part 2 of a multi-step form. Step 1 renders a form, and if it's validated, performs
`return redirect(url_for('personal_open_account', step='2'))`. That is, it calls itself, but with a new `step` parameter. Step 1 completes successfully, and the form is validated (I can see a print statement I put in), but I then immediately receive a BuildError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sth/.virtualenvs/sb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/sth/.virtualenvs/sb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1506, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/sth/.virtualenvs/sb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1504, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/sth/.virtualenvs/sb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1264, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/sth/.virtualenvs/sb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1262, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/sth/.virtualenvs/sb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1248, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/sth/dev/sb_flask/sb/views/personal.py", line 333, in personal_open_account
    return redirect(url_for('personal_open_account', step='2'))
  File "/Users/sth/.virtualenvs/sb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 208, in url_for
    return ctx.url_adapter.build(endpoint, values, force_external=external)
  File "/Users/sth/.virtualenvs/sb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1605, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
BuildError: ('personal_open_account', {'step': '2'}, None)
```

The function itself looks like:

```
@app.route('/personal/save/<product_type>/<slug>/open-account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def personal_open_account(product_type, slug):
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be readily deduced from looking at the code, the product_id and slug arguments weren't being given on subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

`@app.route('/personal/save/<product_type>/<slug>/open-account'` is a wrong way to create an api. Here, you have two indentifiers in continuous `/<product_type>/<slug>/` which is not acceptable to the router.  Try rephrasing the route like this `@app.route('/personal/save/<product_type>/slugs/<slug>/open-account'` .